# How to set view controller as root view in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have an `AppDelegate` and `mainWindow.xib`.  I created another `viewController` and called from `AppDelegate` and it is running good. Now my doubt is whether its possible to make the view controller as root with out adding it to `mainWindow.xib`. Whether its must to load our view with `mainWindow.xib`?

**I am calling view controller like this**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.view = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.view.view];
    self.view.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}
```

Comment: why are all of the answers about UIKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{   
    self.view = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.view;   
}
```

Comment: Declare it by `@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;` or `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;`

Comment: The op is asking a cocoa (desktop osx) question. Where are your `UIWindow` and `UIScreen` classes?

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    self.viewControllerObj = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewControllerObj;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.add this to your appdelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

2.add this to your appdelegate.m in didFinishLaunching method

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```